# How many read/write/delete operations happen here?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How many read/write/delete operations happen in each of the following? I need to create a process that deletes a document from Firebase Firestore and I want to minimize the number of billable operations.

Option 1:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final docRef = await firestore.collection('users').where('username', isEqualTo: username).limit(1).get();
final data = docRef.docs[0].reference;
await data.delete();
```

Option 2:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final docRef = await firestore.collection('users').doc(docID);
await docRef.delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 performs 1 document read operation and 1 document delete operation.

Option 2 performs only 1 document delete operation.

So if you already know the document IDs, you can save cost by *not* reading them first.

Comment: Ahh ok. So getting a document reference doesn't count as a read. Nice, thanks Puf!

Comment: Correct. That's a pure client-side operation, so doesn't need to access any data on the server. Firestore only charged a document read when it needs to read a document on the server on your behalf.